# openCL on consoles for General purpose GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Can we use openCL on consoles like Xbox One and PS4 for General purpose GPU? If yes, can we use openCL framework like ArrayFire - http://arrayfire.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

While the AMD GPU hardware on the most recent version of each console is similar enough to desktop hardware that has OpenCL support, the console vendors do not offer OpenCL as a programming API (unless it's not public information and only available under NDA). If enough game devs asked for it perhaps it would happen.

Comment: How about the previous generation? There are Linux installations possible on a PS3.

Comment: I don't think PS3 supported OpenCL on the Cell, but I think IBM did with their Cell-based system (there are references to Cell in the OpenCL spec).

Comment: I agree, as there seems to be no official API support from IBM. A quick google research found some projects about OpenCL on PS3. In fact, the PS3 is some years older than the OpenCL v1.0 specification..

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for it too! And I've found this discution: [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/666720-can-we-use-opencl-on-consoles/)

Apparently, up to now, the only way out is to use [HLSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/bb509561(v=vs.85).aspx) for Xbox, and [PSSL](http://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdceurope2013/Presentations/825424RichardStenson.pdf) on Playstation. According to a guy on the topic above. They (the APIs) are different, but very similar in such a way that shall be possible to write a code that compiles under both platform using some preprocessors.

PS.: I'm also looking for a good answer for that question. So, if you've found anything around, please post here, I'd love to know ^^